# The following error occurred while executing the dataloader using CLI and ANT

Tags: ant, salesforce, dataloader

BUILD FAILED
`C:\Users\harsridh\Desktop\config\build.xml:73: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\harsridh\Desktop\config\build.xml:52:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Can someone please help me to solve this error? I am basically trying out as per the link. It is all working until Step 6, after which I am getting the error when I run the command ANT ALL.

https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/automate-command-line-dataloader-using-ant-with-dynamic-arguments-and-query/?unapproved=105882&moderation-hash=3d03c6f6dadf1e9b5fbf5ebf499c9413#comment-105882

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

RESOLUTION FOUND
ProcessRunner was altered in some way to where it didn't work past API V51. Download the older version on the following link of the Dataloader.jar file and it should work again.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/tag/v50.0.0